# How to insert double br in ckeditor on single enter key press?

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor

When i enter enter key in ckeditor i want to insert double br there.like (`<br><br>`).my current config in ckeditor is 
    config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
i want to make it to insert double br on single enter key press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use php `str_replace` or in your ckeditor `output` replace all `<br>` to `<br><br>`

```
str_replace("<br>","<br><br>",$output)
```